# Is there a place to test the Blackberry browser?

Tags: blackberry

I have a client that uses Blackberry for mobile and AOL (yes, AOL) on their desktop. I'm trying to figure out how to load the Blackberry OS via virtual machine (downloaded from blackberry site) but no avail. Windows cannot find the extention or load the program.

Is there another (preferably free) way to see what's going on in Blackberry?

Comment: Do you mean a way to simulate what a BlackBerry user sees on their mobile browser?  Have you tried [downloading BlackBerry device simulators](http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/resources/simulators.html)?